# How can i build Detox on Android?

Tags: react-native, detox

Cannot build detox on Android

this is my environment information

info
  React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.6
      CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
      Memory: 1.48 GB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.19.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 13.1, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 28, 29
        Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2
        System Images: android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203
      Xcode: 11.1/11A1027 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.3 => 16.8.3
      react-native: 0.59.10 => 0.59.10
    npmGlobalPackages:
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1

this is the issue:

detox build -c android.emu.debug
detox[3382] INFO:  [build.js] cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..

> Configure project :react-native-firebase
>   react-native-firebase: using React Native prebuilt binary from /Users/hiperezr/Code/bitbucket/mobile-clock/node_modules/react-native/android
>
> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   /Users/hiperezr/Code/bitbucket/mobile-clock/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerModule.java:16: error: package com.facebook.react.module.annotations does not exist
>   import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule;